# JMeter - Unable to capture the request after click on download link

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am facing one of the problem in my application at the time of downloading a file. I am unable to capture the request after click on download link. So may be anybody can guide me how to capture these requests with JMeter?

Steps:

1. Click on Download link
2. Save the file
3. Select the drive/location where to save
4. Click save button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sam mentions when you click "Download" link or button the majority of browsers send GET request for the content and start downloading it in background into temp folder. After you choose the destination the browser just copies the file.

If you need to test the performance of web server on multiple and/or concurrent downloads you just need to simulate GET requests.

If you need to perform some operations on downloaded files, i.e. check size, integrity, type, etc. JMeter offers [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) Listener which can store any response including Download one into a file.

See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for more details on implementation.

Answer (score 1):

When you download a file through your browser like that, it is just making a simple http get request, similar to other requests.  The differences is that the browser recognizes that the resource it is getting is not something to parse as html and attempt to display, but to download instead.

Some browser tools, and the jmeter recorder don't usually pick up those requests.  You can use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to see the requests and then create the requests from scratch in jmeter using the info from the request you see in the other tool.